# Keyboard auto on in Android

Tags: android, xml, keyboard

I want to implement a tablet in Android app that keyboard auto on the screen. Now my situation is I add a edit-text in a xml file, and when clicking the edit-text, keyboard appears, I want to show keyboard auto on. 
When users click on the check mark, the keyboard disappears, but I want that keyboard will not be dismissed and clicking on check mark means checking the input.
Any samples or help is appreciated!

Comment: @ try to add some code here so we can understand clearly

Comment: Sorry, Firefog, I still haven't wrote that code, and I will try the method others provide, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Use below method with activity**

```
//To show the keyboard
public void showKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if(activity.getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

//To hide the keyboard
public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        if(activity.getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

**OR**

**Use below method with EditText**

```
//To show the keyboard
public void showSoftKeyboard(EditText editText) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }

//To hide the keyboard
    `public void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText editText) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

*Use above method as per your requirement*

Answer (score 0):

Check with this:
Add this on your checkbox click

To Show Soft Keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);     
imm.showSoftInput(EDITABLE_VIEW,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

OR

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

To Hide Soft Keyboard:

```
 InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager)
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(FOCUSABLE_VIEW.getWindowToken(), 0);

Here, “FOCUSABLE_VIEW” can be any view which is visible on screen like
```

Refer:http://chintanrathod.com/show-hide-soft-keyboard-programmatically-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Below are the methods to show and hide keyboard. Have a look.

```
public static void ShowKeyboard(Activity activity, View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
            view.getApplicationWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}

public static void HideKeyBoard(Activity activity) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputMethodManager.isAcceptingText())
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you want to open keyboard on activity start, you can add following code in `<activity>` tag in manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

this will show the keyboard whenever you start activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code,

editext.requestfocus();

this will automatically brings the keyboard.

Do not use,
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
inside your android manifest file...

just remove "android:windowSoftInputMode"  from your Activity.

Comment: I am sorry but editext.requestfocus(); dose not work for me.   This is my code :          LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.ms_pdf_viewer_support, container, false);    EditText editText=(EditText) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText);     editText.requestFocus();

Comment: Don't use the following inside your Android  Manifestfile,

Answer (score 0):

This will work and also always try to use **etText.requestfocus();** it will automatically open a keyboard 
and 
    public static void ShowKeyboard(Activity activity, View v)
     {

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
        view.getApplicationWindowToken(),
        InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

}

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, guys! It is my mistake to not to describe the problem more clear. I want to create a dialog, and there is a edittext in the dialog, I want soft keyboard auto on when the dialog show. I have find a way to solve it, this is my code:                                              Dialog dialog = new MyDialog(getActivity());
 dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
 dialog.show();

Comment: oh thats really great wang! keep it up!